# Suppose c is an arbitrary natural number that satisfies the form cⁿ=(b+1)ⁿ-1+b(a-1)d. Now, given that a+b>c>b, show that d=n.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was wondering whether anyone had any suggestions as to how to go about the following problem.

Let $a,b,c,d,n ∈ ℕ, n,d≥2$. Suppose c is an arbitrary natural number that satisfies the form $$cⁿ=(b+1)ⁿ-1+b(a-1)d.$$ Now, given that $a+b>c>b$, show that $d=n$.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample. Let $a=2,b=1,c=2$ and $n>1$ arbitrary. Then
$c^n=2^n$ and $(b+1)^n-1+b(a-1)d=2^n-1+d$. Hence $d=1$, but $n>1$ arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks for outlining this. I had d too loosely defined. Having looked back at the precursors to the problem, I should have realised and stated that d≥2.